# Почему 0 === -0 выводит true

Tags: javascript

Нашел такой код в просторах интернета.

```js
console.log(0 === -0) // true
```

Прочитал стандарт [**тут**](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) потом [**это**](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/is-negative-zero-0-a-number-in-javascript-c62739f80114), но я все равно не понял почему - и плюс и минус сбрасывается с нулю.

> “Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic, the number 0 does not have a sign, so that −0, +0 and 0 are identical.

Comment: Формальный ответ — так написано в стандарте: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-equal

Comment: А реально, кому и зачем было бы нужно что бы эти значения различались в реальном коде?

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за то что скинули ссылку из стандарта которая и так была в вопросе.

Comment: @Demon__ В математике конечно можно спорить, равен ли +0 и -0  (в арифметике равен, в теории пределов - нет), но то как будет себя вести язык определяется именно стандартом и вопрос почему тут не уместен, ведь единственный адекватный ответ на него - потому что создатели стандарта так решили.

Comment: `почему - и плюс и минус сбрасывается с нулю.` Ну... потому что `In ordinary arithmetic, the number 0 does not have a sign, so that −0, +0 and 0 are identical.` На практике обычно удобно считать, что нуль равен нулю. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @T0xee.n17 благодарю